# Very strange Reshape layer behavier in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

**keras:** 2.2.4 
**tf:** 1.15.0

while I create a net,like this:

```
print(priorbox3.shape) #got (?, 38, 38, 3, 8)
priorbox3_reshape = Reshape((38*38*3, 4))(priorbox3)
print(priorbox3_reshape.shape) #(?, 4332, 4)
```

It runs successfully, but in fact `38 * 38 * 3 * 8 != 4332 * 4!`
Very strange, and if I `set Reshape((38 * 38 * 3, 8))`, I will get a mismatch error.

Comment: I sovle this by rewrite the layer function: compute_output_shape.

Answer (score 0):

Reshape layer doesn't check the dimension integrity because underlying this, it's a tensorflow (if you use tensorflow as backend) placeholder. The question mark in the beginning means it can be anything. So it means no matter how you reshape, it's a valid shape because the ? stands for anything. in your case. 38x38x3x8 / 4 = 8664. However you specified 4332 which means there will be 2 dimension gets into the reshaped tensor's question mark. In the run time, let's say your batch size is 4, then your reshaped one should be `(8, 4332, 4)` then tf will raise runtime error.

Again Reshape layer is just to construct a graph. Errors are deferred to runtime in this case

Comment: Thx！My backend is tf, the first dimension is batchsize and its fixed.
Also as I said,  if I set Reshape((38 * 38 * 3, 8)), I will get a mismatch error.